# Rails - belongs_to ignores inverse_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I've got two AR Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key 'email'
  attr_readonly :email, :etag, :full_name, :google_id, :photo_url, :suspended
  has_one :sip_user, inverse_of: :user, foreign_key: 'user_email'
end

class SipUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key 'user_email'
  attr_readonly :user_email, :sip_id, :sip_password,
                :int_number, :ext_number, :mobile_number
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :sip_user, foreign_key: 'email'
end
```

Querying from User to SipUser works perfectly:

```
User.find('email@company.com').sip_user
```

returns the correct matching SIP user.

```
SipUser.find('email@company.com')
```

also returns a correct DB entry, but

```
SipUser.find('email@company.com').user
```

doesn't. But it should, according to the belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :sip_user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `inverse_of` has no nothing to do with the  `SipUser.find('email@company.com').user` expression. You specification in SipUser means this: For this sip_user, find the user that has `user.email= sip_user.email`. This leads to this query `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email='email@company.com' LIMIT 1;` 
Your inverse_of would help with this case `sip_user.user.sip_user`. If you do not have inverse_of, it will use two query, first one finds the user for the sip_user, and a second one finds the sip_user for the sip_user.user. With inverse_of, it will only send the first query and immediately returns sip_user as sip_user.user.sip_user. So it helps with your DB efficiency.